# Is there any way to colorize the output of a Linux command?

Tags: linux, command-line, colors

I'm kind of new to Linux, but I'm guessing that you could pass the output of a program to a particular script and have it display it in various colors, based on some regular expressions (constructed from some kind of config file perhaps).

Comment: seems like a pre-dupe of https://superuser.com/questions/602294/is-there-colorizer-utility-that-can-take-command-output-and-colorize-it-accordin

Answer (score 4):

[MultiTail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) has support for colorizing logs according to some (possibly preconfigured) patterns.

[Log Tool](http://xjack.org/logtool/) is another example of such software.

Answer (score 3):

[Supercat](http://supercat.nosredna.net/index.html) (spc) works really well. It's in the Debian and Ubuntu repositories and may be in others.

Answer (score 2):

Also [`colout` Color Up Arbitrary Command Ouput](http://nojhan.github.io/colout/):

> `colout` is a simple command to add colors to a text stream in your
>   terminal.
>
> The `colout` command line interface has been carefully designed to be
>   simple. Basically, you will call it like: `<text stream> | colout <pattern to color> [color [style]]`
>
> `colout` has the ability to use 8 colors mode, 256 colors mode,
>   colormaps, themes and source code syntax coloring. Patterns are
>   regular expressions.
>
> You can think of colout as an alternative to grep --color which will
>   preserve the surrounding context, with more powerful coloring
>   capabilities.

Comment: This is a neat tool with a nice interface.  It is too bad that it isn't in recent Ubuntu repos and the `pip install` is broken.