# Is there colorizer utility that can take command output and colorize it accordingly to pre-defined scheme?

Tags: command-line, unix, colors

I already know that I can [colorize output with grep](https://superuser.com/questions/358875/how-to-color-grep-output) and with a couple of different ways. I want to have something like [supercat](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/1005732), but for commands (and not that dead).

> The application Supercat colors any input text based on the type of
>   file and a set of rules associated with the file type. The rules are
>   used to match strings found in the input text and can be specified
>   using simple characters or strings, regular expressions and special
>   time-formatting rules.

Lets say, I'm writing `magiccommand gcc blah blah`, this magic command understands that it has to colorify gcc output and chooses one template. Now, I'm willing to `magiccommand mvn foo bar` and that command takes another appropriate rule. Bonus points for readable rules -- no `"s/^GET.*$/\x1b[31m&\x1b[0m/"` sed insanity.

Comment: Why is this closed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a tool like [grcat](http://man.cx/grcat(1))/[grc](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/grc/) (where the first is the tool, and the second the front end).

> grc will execute command command with optional parameters [args]
>   piping its stdout or stderr into grcat, with apropriate configuration
>   file.

For example

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### `source-highlight`

You may also find interesting `source-highlight` [released under GNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/).
You can add it as alias e.g. in your `.bash_aliases` with something like the line below.

```
alias Cat='source-highlight --out-format=esc -o STDOUT -i'  
Cat myfile.c # or myfile.xml ...
```

Or you can do a similar alias (without the `-i`at the end to have the possibility to *pipe in*)

```
alias PCat='source-highlight --out-format=esc -o STDOUT '
tail myfile.sh | PCat     # Note the absence of the `-i`
```

[image: Screen Example]

Excerpt from `apt-cache show  source-highlight`:

> Description-en: **convert source code to syntax highlighted document.**
>    This program, given a source file, produces a document with syntax
>    highlighting.
>    It supports syntax **highlighting for over 100 file formats**, including
>    major programming languages, markup formats, and configuration file
>    formats. For output, the following formats are supported: HTML,
>    XHTML, LaTeX, Texinfo, **ANSI color escape sequences**, and DocBook

Among the options that you can read from `man source-highlight` the **`-s`**

> **-s**, **--src-lang**=STRING source language (use --lang-list to get the complete list).  **If not specified, the source language  will  be guessed from the file extension**.
>
> --lang-list
>    list all the supported language and associated language definition file

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `grc` is you can't pipe into it, but you can pipe to its underlying `grcat` program. So first:

Install `grcat`

```
sudo apt-get install grc
```

Now execute:

```
echo "[SEVERE] Service is down" | grcat ~/conf.username
```

Where `conf.myusername` contains:

```
regexp=SEVERE
colours=on_red
count=more
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [ccat](https://github.com/jingweno/ccat/)

`$ ccat file.yml
$ ccat file.py
$ ccat file.rb
$ ccat file.go
...`

Answer (score 1):

there's also https://github.com/dalance/pipecolor it's similar to grcat but written in rust.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.